# In c++ what is the difference between a char and a const * char and why can't you add two chars together

Tags: c++, char

I am trying t create an array of System commands to change the color of the command line on windows.

I have an array which stores chars such as "AA" or "B4", I just need to pass this through the System() command.

In order to change the color I must add the hexadecimal value to the char "Color", to make "Color XX" (XX being the hexadecimal color value).

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: The difference is that one type can hold a single character, and the other is a pointer to a constant (read-only) character.

Comment: `"AA"` is a const char array literal not a char. You probably want to read about [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) in 1st place.

Comment: lol how fast are you at typing is what the question should of been

Comment: In addition to the comment by @πάνταῥεῖ, the string literal `"AA"` is not only a constant (read-only) array of characters, it also have the length *3*. The length is 3 because the array also contains the string terminator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const` means constant, so `const char*` means a constant char pointer, or a char pointer that cannot be modified, but a `char` can be modified because it is not a constant, but can only hold one character because it isn't a pointer (a.k.a. a char array). Anyway, have you tried combining the two variables with `strcat(CHAR1, CHAR2)`?

Comment: _'adding the two chars'_ you are re(mis-)using this term again! It's not _"two chars"_ as I mentioned in my comment on the question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Is "combining the two variables" better?

Comment: Not ideal (OP wasn't talking about variables at all), but better, yes.